# VBA copy data from multiple files into 1 file

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to loop through excel files within a given folder (These files are updated during the morning) and extract data into a new excel file and save it.

There are about 10 files on average to copy data from.

My question is: What would the loop code look like? Any help would be appreciated to get me started in the right direction. This is for work, just trying to improve processes.

Comment: Under "related" on the right of this page there are a list of suggested previous questions - I would start there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Combine_workbooks()
Path = "C:\Users\PChen\Desktop\Test\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Workbooks.Add
  Do While FileName <> ""
  Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True
  Call AuthOpenAll
  Worksheets("Data").Activate
  Worksheets("Data").Copy After:=Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("sheet1")
     Workbooks(FileName).Close savechanges:=False
     FileName = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

}